# Difference between running 'bash' and `source ./bashrc`

Tags: linux, bash

When you type "bash" at a bash prompt, it starts a new bash process.

I am curious what `source ./bashrc` does. Here are my following questions:

1. What does `source OOOO` do?
2. It appears to me running `bash` and `source ./bashrc` returns same result. Is it true?

Comment: 1. what does `help source` tell you it does? 2. please define "returns" and "result"

Comment: Running `bash` creates a *new* interactive shell (which implicitly sources `.bashrc`).

Answer (score 0):

1. `source ~/.bashrc` means applies changes in `.bashrc` into current session.
2. `bash` executes commands from stdin or stdout or a file.